# How to send Map Location from Android to a PHP SOAP web service

Tags: php, android, web-services, soap, gps

I created a soap web service using PHP which is connected to a database.
and i want to use my Android Mobile phone to send my map location to the SOAP server.

What is the logic behind this and if possible can someone give me a code example for this process. am i going to use PHP or java?

I already made the client and server.php and i just don't know what to do next

Comment: Please note that this is a question and answer site, not a
code writing service. If you [edit] your question to
describe what you have tried so far and where you are stuck,
then we can try to help with specific problems. You should
also read [ask].

Comment: I already made the client and server.php and i just don't know what to do next, i just want a code for an app to send the map from my android mobile phone to the php web server, i need to know what code am i going to use from the android side and how i will receive the data from the php server side

Comment: and i don't ask for a code, i just ask for the logic or a help or website to look into to guide me